# Why do I get an empty page before my title page?

Tags: titles, page-numbering, mac, texworks

Unfortunately, I get two empty pages before my title page. This is a code example:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\title{title}
\author{Name Name}
\maketitle
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\linespread{1.1}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Name Name}

\section*{Abstract}
```

The first page has no page number, the second with the title and author does has a 2 and the next one starts again with 1...

Comment: use `titlepage` (to lay it out by hand) or `\maketitle` to use the class defined laout: don't use both

Comment: Thank you, however this does not change the fact that there is still an empty page before the title...

Comment: Yes exactly: just remove the titlepage and center environments and just have `\maketitle` as intended, and the title comes on page 1 You basically have two titlepages (one blank) as you have used two methods of making a title.

Comment: When I remove 'maketitle', I don't see any title, just an empty first page. When I remove 'titlepage', I see a title on the second page together with the abstract, but also an empty first page

Comment: Try `book` or `report` class.

Comment: @Jesse I still get the empty page

Comment: The first is as expected `titlepage` just makes a blank page it is up to you to use \large and \textbf or whatever to fill it as needed. If you just use \maketitle then the title comes on page 1, in fact your MWE is only one page long (I tested it:-)

Comment: @C.Colden -- same as David Carlisle, but use `report` or `book`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `titlepage` (which makes a blank page in which to typeset title elements) and `\maketitle` Use one or the other. This makes a 1 page document with a title on that page.

```
\documentclass[english,12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{Name Name}
\maketitle


\linespread{1.1}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Name Name}

\section*{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David. I forgot to remove the '\begin{center}'