# Show title page twice at pdf start

Tags: titles, amsbook

Because of the spcification of my university I have to print the title page twice at the start of the deliverable pdf. I tried to to that but couldn't. I am using the amsbook class and created the following MWE. The problem is that there are two blank pages inserted before the title pages. Is there any way to remove them from being inserted (so that the two title pages are the first two pdf pages)? Also note that the titling package isn't compatible with the amsbook class.

```
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Start}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `titlepage` together with `\maketitle`, you need to choose either one; see also [Why do I get an empty page before my title page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175835/4778) for more details. But the summary is that the first one will create a blank page for you to enter a custom title page, and since the second one creates blank pages automatically, you get multiple blank pages when using both together.

Since the two title pages are the same, you can enclose it in a `\newcommand` in the preamble so it's easier to edit.

### Code

```
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{afterpage} % for the blank page

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\newcommand\mycustomtitle{%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\Huge Title}\par
\emph{Author}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}%
}

\begin{document}
\mycustomtitle
%
\mycustomtitle

\afterpage{\null\newpage} % insert a blank page

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Start}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works as advertised.